# I'd like to use Perl regular expression in PHP

Tags: php, perl

I wanto use perl reqexp in PHP.

For example,

Perl:

```
$url =~ qr{https?://([^\/\?&:#]+\.)?example.com};
```

PHP:

```
preg_match("/https?:\/\/([^\/\?&:#]+\.)?example\.com/", $url);
```

Comment: You did not ask a question. and you want to use parse_url

Comment: if you want to validate the URL via regex. Please do not do it. use `filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)` instead...

Answer (score 7):

You answered your own question? `preg_match` is able to process virtually all of Perl regex syntax. (The "p" is for "Perl".)

Learn more about PHP `preg_match` in its [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php).

Comment: Thank you for your question.
Can I use another delimiter, like @.

Comment: Yes. The first character of the argument will be used as the delimiter.

Comment: See [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) for the delimiter documentation.

Comment: I want to change the delimiter

Comment: thank you. I've checked it.
Should I escape "."?

Comment: @masa that depends on what you want to do ;)

Comment: Just FYI, you shouldn't expect 100% compatibility. I've had some problems with preg_* and complex expressions. Believe it was in php 5.3.

Answer (score 1):

You have used the right function `preg_match`. Now regarding the capturing of the match, you need to pass another argument:

```
preg_match("/https?:\/\/([^\/\?&:#]+\.)?example\.com/", $url, $match);
```

and the match will be available in `$match[1]`.

Comment: I'd like to use Perl reqexp,

preg_match("qr{https?://([^\/\?&:#]+\.)?example.com}", $url);

Because reqexp strings are stored in a configuration file.

Comment: `qr` is a Perl operator, which is to say Perl code. Not a regex (that's what `qr` returns when executed). Not a regex pattern (that's what's inside the curlies). You shouldn't have code (`qr`) in a data file!

Comment: if this file were not "qr", i'm glad.
but lots of program use that configuration file.